# Construct a basis for a finite subspace of the Function Space V

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let X a non empty set, $F$ a field and $V$ the set of function of $X$ on $F$. If $f,g \in V$  and $\lambda \in F$ , $f +g ,\lambda f \in V$ are the functions such that $\forall x \in X$,
$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(\lambda f)(x) = \lambda f(x)$.

How can i construct a basis if $X = \{x_1,...,x_n \}$.

I really stuck in this problem some help please.

Comment: Hint: A function on your (_finite_) set $X$ is just an ordered $n$-tuple of elements of $F$; what do your vector space operations reduce to?

Comment: then $f = (f(x_1),f(x_2),..., f(x_n))$ and we can indetify V with the cartesian power ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $f_1(x_1) = 1$, $f_1(x_2) = 0$, $f_2(x_1) = 0$, $f_2(x_2)=1$. Obviously, $f_1,f_2 \in V$. Now take an arbitrary $f \in V$, and observe that $$
  f(x) = f_1(x)\cdot f(x_1) + f_2(x)\cdot f(x_2) \quad \text{for $x \in \{x_1,x_2\}$.}
$$
Now generalize this idea to $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ instead of just $x_1,x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the map $\varphi\colon V\to F^n$ defined by
$$
\varphi(f)=\begin{bmatrix}f(x_1)\\f(x_2)\\\vdots\\f(x_n)\end{bmatrix}
$$
This map is linear and an isomorphism.